Pure state vs mixed state (experimental standpoint)
Given the theoretical definition of pure state in density matrix formalism:
$$|\psi_{\text{pure}}\rangle = \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle$$
$$\rho_{pure} = |\psi_{\text{pure}} \rangle \langle \psi_{\text{pure}}|$$
and statistical mixture state:
$$\rho_{\text{mixed}} = \Sigma_k p_k |\psi_k \rangle \langle \psi_k|$$
where {$|\psi_k \rangle$} is some set of pure states.
All examples of statistical mixture that I have seen online are not pure. I am confused, since all quantum measurement we can perform only yield probabilistic result in the basis that we select. And yet we can repeatedly prepare the initial state $\psi_{\text{in}}$ and perform Quantum State Tomography (QST) to reconstruct a pure state (assuming no decoherence from measurement). The process of performing QST is repeated preparation of initial state $|\psi_{\text{in}} \rangle$ and measurement in different basis ($\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z$), and we can use
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{2}(I+X\sigma_x+Y\sigma_y+Z\sigma_z)
$$
to reconstruct a pure density matrix.
Then the following question arise: if we perform repeated measurement of a pure initial state $|\psi_{\text{in}} \rangle$ to obtain the statistical results and by using $\rho_{\text{mixed}} = \Sigma_k p_k |\psi_k \rangle \langle \psi_k|$, can get a pure state, since we are essentially measuring the same thing from the case of QST? If we can reconstruct the pure state from QST, we should be able to reconstruct a pure state this way as well.
To test my theory out, I design a simple simulation:
Suppose we have an initial pure state
$$
\psi_{\text{in}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|0\rangle + |1\rangle)
$$
We perform total N measurements in the three Pauli basis randomly to obtain the probability of result $p_k$ for each pure state. And by using $\rho_{\text{mixed}} = \Sigma_k p_k |\psi_k \rangle \langle \psi_k|$ to reconstruct the statistical ensemble, where
$$|\psi_k \rangle \in \{|+x\rangle, |-x\rangle, |+y\rangle, |-y\rangle, |0\rangle, |1\rangle\}$$
the resulting $\rho$ should be pure.
However, the simulation result doesn't align with my theory. I perform total 10,000 measurements randomly in the three Pauli basis. The probability of each pure state is
p_arr = [0.3375, 0.0, 0.165, 0.1692, 0.1659, 0.1624] # +x, -x, +y, -y, +z, -z

And using this probability to construct $\rho$, I got
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0.50175+0.j & 0.16875+0.0021j \\
0.16875-0.0021j & 0.49825+0.j
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is clearly not a pure state. But from the probability array, we can also get the necessary data to compute the expectation value of $X, Y, Z$ and construct a pure state density matrix from
$$
\rho = \frac{1}{2}(I+X\sigma_x+Y\sigma_y+Z\sigma_z)
$$
Why is this the case? Are there any subtle details in probability or quantum mechanics that I am missing to fully understand the difference between pure state, mixed state, and quantum measurement?

Hi, and welcome to Physics SE. To get $\langle$ and $\rangle$, use \langle and \rangle, respectively. For example, it will produce $|\psi\rangle$.

I'm confused about what you're asking. How do you "get" your $\rho_{\rm mixed}$ from measurements on a pure state? If you are talking about doing state tomography, you get something close to the state you're measuring (how close depends on statistics, specifics of the measurement, specific method, etc). If the input state is modelled as a statistical mixture, that's what you'll get from tomography. For pure inputs, you'll still statistically never get a pure state from tomography with finite statistics, but your estimate will get closer and closer to a pure state increasing the statistics

Basically no part of what you are doing is correct. You have not understood what it is you are supposed to do to do QST properly.
You are using your simulation wrongly. Luckily, your simulation is tolerable and we can use its output.
With your simulation output, you should have obtained $$X=1\pm0,\ Y=-0.0126\pm0.0173,\ Z=0.0107\pm0.0175$$ which should then give you that it is a pure state, within error bars.
I mean, you clearly started with a pure state; if your QST does not return that you have a pure state, obviously you have done something wrong. QST should be able to reproduce your initial quantum state density operator $\rho$, be it mixed or pure. It is not very exciting to reproduce a pure state's density operator, and so it is more instructive to get the density operator of a mixed state.
You have too many confusions to begin to untangle.

Thanks for your answer! But I still have a remaining question. Can we have a statistical mixture state (=Σ|⟩⟨|) that is pure?

As long as it is not one single $p_k=1$ and the rest are all zero, then it is impure. The extremely cheap way to check, is to just take your density operator, and square it. If it is not equal to itself, then it is clearly impure.
